# Deadline exceeded error even it simple square root function?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, rpc

I'm very new gRPC, I have tried increasing the deadline value from 1000 to 10000000000

Here the code:

client.js

```
const path = require('path');

const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');

const packageDefinitition = protoLoader.loadSync(
  path.join(__dirname, '../protos/advanced.proto'),
  {
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true
  }
);

const advancedProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinitition).advanced;

function main() {
  const client = new advancedProto.Advanced(
    'localhost:50051',
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
  );

  client.SqaureRoot({ number: 1 }, { deadline: 10000000000 }, function (err, response) {
    console.log(err, response);
  });
}

main();
```

server.js

```
const path = require('path');

const grpc = require('@grpc/grpc-js');
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');

const packageDefinitition = protoLoader.loadSync(
  path.join(__dirname, '../protos/advanced.proto'),
  {
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true
  }
);

const advancedProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinitition).advanced;

function SqaureRoot(call, callback) {
  if (call.request.number > 0) {
    return callback(null, { result: call.request.number * call.request.number });
  }
  return callback({
    code: grpc.status.INVALID_ARGUMENT,
    message: "The number is not greater than 0"
  })
}

function main() {
  const Server = new grpc.Server();

  Server.addService(advancedProto.Advanced.service, { SqaureRoot });

  Server.bindAsync("127.0.0.1:50051", grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(), function() {
    Server.start();
    console.log(`Server running at 127.0.0.1:50051`);
  });
}

main();
```

proto_file

```
syntax = "proto3";

package advanced;

service Advanced {

  // error handling
  rpc SqaureRoot (SquareRootRequest) returns (SquareRootResponse) {};
}

message SquareRootRequest {
  int32 number = 1;
}

message SquareRootResponse {
  double result = 1;
}
```

When i execute the code from client i get this error whatever deadline value is

```
node client
Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/Users/Desktop/own/grpc-workspace/advanced/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/Desktop/own/grpc-workspace/advanced/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:180:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/Desktop/own/grpc-workspace/advanced/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/Users/Desktop/own/grpc-workspace/advanced/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)
    at /Users/Desktop/own/grpc-workspace/advanced/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:160:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  code: 4,
  details: 'Deadline exceeded',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} }
} undefined
```

If i change the deadline value to Infinity then it works. But i want to know why does simple square root function does not accept the deadline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really helps that you included a good repro!

I think your issue is that deadlines are points in time (not durations).

So you'll want to calculate the deadline from now plus some duration:

```js
let d = new Date();
let deadline = d.setSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 5);

client.SquareRoot({
  number: 1,
}, {
  deadline: deadline,
}, (err, response) => {
  console.log(err, response);
});
```

> **NOTES**
> your code will work but:
>
> 1. you've a typo `SqaureRoot` and e.g. `SquareRoot[Request|Response]`.
> 2. `SqaureRoot` (sic.) calculates the square not the square root ;-)
> 3. You may want to give your package and service more distinct names to avoid `advanced.Advanced`
> 4. `server.start()` is blocking and so you may want to put the `console.log("server starting")` before it.

Comment: `server.start()` is not blocking. It actually does very little work.